# Count words and numbers in one word PHP

Tags: php, split, cpu-word

I have to count the words in a string.

```
$string = "Patrick Kelly born in Italy. Tel. 654 646 547";
print_r (str_word_count ($string, 2, '.0123456789'));
```

Everything works fine, but in this case I also have to count the numbers. The str_word_count function works like this, but counts each number with a space separately. In my case, he should treat the number 654 646 547 as one word, not three.

Do you have any idea how to do it? Thanks for helping

Comment: Should any sequence of digits be treated as one number, or just things you consider to be phone numbers?

Comment: @AlexHowansky  any sequence of digits be treated as one number

Comment: So spaces are important for this assignment, but nothing else? Feels like a split with a loop, and if the previous item and the current item are both numeric, don’t count it.

Comment: Remove the whitespace between digits first maybe? https://3v4l.org/J3QnQ